# How to use computed field in xml file without store in database in Odoo

Tags: xml, odoo-11

First I create one compute field to inherit ir.model Like this :

```py
    from odoo import api, fields, models, _
    from odoo.http import request

    class ir_models(models.Model):
      _inherit = 'ir.model'
    
    website_models = fields.Boolean('Allowed Website Model' ,compute='_is_website_models')

@api.depends('website_models')     
def _is_website_models(self):                 
    for models in self:
        fields = request.env['ir.model.fields'].search([('model_id', '=', models.id)])            
        for field in fields:
            if field.name == 'website_url':
                models.website_models = True
```

Then I want to use this field into xml file(into view)

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <odoo>
    <record id="view_res_config_settings_website_search_ept"      model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="model">res.config.settings</field>
    <field name="inherit_id" ref="website.res_config_settings_view_form"/>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <xpath expr="//div[@id='languages_setting']" position="after">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 o_setting_box" id="model_settings">
                <div class="o_setting_right_pane">
                    <label string="Website Serach"/>
                    <div class="text-muted">
                         <b>Configure Models Name</b>                             
                    </div>
                    <field name="model_id" widget="many2many_tags" domain="[('website_models', '=', True)]"/>                                                                                                     
                </div>
            </div>
        </xpath>
    </field>
</record>
```

But it is not use in xml file because this field is not store in database.
Then How to use it?

Comment: Please pick the "odoo" tag that matches the version you are actually using.

Comment: I'm working in odoo v'11

Answer (score 0):

While using compute field when should mention `store = True` in field paramater.

```
website_models = fields.Boolean('Allowed Website Model',compute='_is_website_models',store=True)
```

It will store the field in Database.